# Android Apps from Old Tablet to New Tablet

Tags: applications, google-play-store, data-transfer

I have a Motorola Xoom running Jelly Bean and am moving to the Asus TFT-700. I plan on giving my Xoom to someone in a factory default condition so that my Google account will only be on the Asus. Do I really need to remember all of my installed apps so that they can be manually downloaded to the Asus or will my Google account take care of this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Google's backup service is described on [one of their support pages](http://support.google.com/android/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=168906):

> ## Backing up and restoring your data
>
> You can back up your settings and other data with your Google Account,
> so if you ever replace your tablet, you can restore your data on the
> new one. If you choose to use this service, your data is backed up
> automatically.
>
> If you previously used the backup service with the Google Account you
> just used to sign in, you can also choose to restore your settings
> from your Google Account to your tablet now.
>
> Important: If you want to restore your settings, you must do that now
> during setup. You can’t restore data after setup is complete.
>
> Many kinds of data are backed up, including:
>
> - Your Android settings, such as your Wi-Fi networks and passwords,
>   user dictionary, and so on
> - Many Google application settings, such as
>   your Browser bookmarks
> - The apps you download from Android Market Some
>   third-party apps also make use of the backup service, so if you
>   reinstall one, its settings and data are restored

Comment: When presenting content that is from another site/person, please cite it (i.e. provide a link) to give proper credit to the original author(s). Preferably, use the quote block functionality so that others will know you are quoting another source.

Answer (score 1):

Using Google's backup service (as [described by greg](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/38874/16575)) is one way. But as in the past this did not prove very reliable (it should have improved with 4.x, though), plus apps have to actively support it (which by far not all do), there are alternatives to consider.

Since Android 4.0, you can perform [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/16575). You can also backup/restore single apps (including their data) this way.

An easier approach is using Koush's [Carbon Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup) -- at least if you buy the Pro license (less than 4 Euro). Install the app on both devices, and you can sync apps and data between the two (see the second "tab" in the screenshot<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/424XW.jpg)</sup>).

[image: Carbon Backup]

Answer (score 0):

I would use Google backup for any personal data or other data and [Appmonster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.android_telefonie.appmanager) for the apps. The free version can batch backup all the apps on your device to a `.apk` format which you could batch reinstall onto the new device once Appmonster is installed on it.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Your answer is much more valuable if you provide a link to the Appmonster software.

Comment: While *AppMonster* certainly is a good thing here (especially for having previous versions of apps available using its auto-backup feature), batch mode just works with the paid version. Moreover, I wouldn't trust *Google Backup* for a cent (I mean, backup works -- but I wouldn't expect restore to work): first, it only backs up a subset of your data (apps must actively support it), and second it's quite unreliable. See the [backup tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info) for alternative backup methods.

Comment: @THelper Thanks for the advice! Will do so in future.